# Setting RepositoryPath at a project level

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have a project that is shared between two solutions and I am trying to have that project place all of its nuget files into a common location. I've seen lots of stuff describing how to do it by placing a nuget.config file in the solution folder. However I NEED to have it scoped to the project, due to MsBuild/MsDeploy.

I've tried placing a nuget.config file in the project folder, but it seems to be completely ignored.

I tried following this [Nuget Doc](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/Release-Notes/NuGet-2.1#Specify_%e2%80%98packages%e2%80%99_Folder_Location). But its ignoring my settings.

Comment: `I am trying to have that project place all of its nuget files into a common location.` - why?

Comment: @manojlds because its a WCF interface dll. If it builds from one set of dlls on the client and one set of dlls on the server that would be bad. Plus I need to run Msbuild against the project and NOT the solution for MsDeploy to work (blame the MS engineers).

Comment: Nuget packages are bound to the solution, not the project. So I don't think there is any way to do what you want.

Comment: Why don't you create a Nuget package from the project that the solutions are sharing?

Comment: I had considered it. However it would only solve a very limited subset of the problem (re production builds of the interface project). Whilst generally developing, it would be extremely difficult for developers to develop the interface project without "testing in production".